# Directory Administrator Account Disabled

Tags: password, ldap

Mac OS X 10.11.6 running Server with OpenDirectory Master. The Directory Administrator account password expired and an administrator keyed it multiple times causing it to become locked. The process to reset the Directory Administrator Password (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200182)  works fine. However, the account remains locked out (disabled). How can we get this account re-enabled?

Comment: By „locked out“, do you mean you cannot login locally or via ssh?

Comment: By locked out I mean the account has become disabled. We are talking about the Directory Administrator. It cannot authenticate because it is disabled. We have resolved the issue. I will post solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by clearing the domain account policies by issuing the following command:

`sudo pwpolicy -n /LDAPv3/ldapi://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fldapi clearaccountpolicies`

This resulted in the account becoming re-enabled because the policies which led to it's disablement no longer existed. We were then able to reset the Directory Administrators password again following the procedure details here: [Reset the Open Directory administrator password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200182).

Comment: reminder to creating an additionally account?